# Using Zend Controllers with numeric Actions

Tags: php, zend-framework

Usually if I wanted to create a page `/user/profile` i would create the function `profileAction()` in the User Controller.
Now if I want to create a page called `/error/404` i can't create a `404Action()` because of the syntx error `unexpected '404', expecting 'identifier'`
Is there a way I can create pages with numbers like that?

Comment: have you tried using Zend router to handle this?

Comment: Just a suggestion: I use `e404Action` (and so on).

Comment: +1 to genious ^^ And if you absolutely want a url like `http://domain.com/error/404` then use a static route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to define a custom route as follows:

```
resources.routes.error.route = "/error/:id"
resources.routes.error.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route" 
resources.routes.error.defaults.module = default
resources.routes.error.defaults.controller = error
resources.routes.error.defaults.action = index
resources.routes.error.reqs.id = "\d+"
```

Than in your the indexAction you would forward to an action for a specific error code. For example, for 404 error:

```
class ErrorController extends Zend_Controller_Action {


    public function indexAction() {
        $errorId = $this->_getParam('id', null);            
        return $this->_forward("error$errorId" );
    }

    public function error404Action() {
        echo "error 404"; 
    }
}
```

This is very simplified example, but it should be enough to show how it could be done.

Another way, instead of forwarding, would be just to render appropriate view script, e.g.

```
class ErrorController extends Zend_Controller_Action {


    public function indexAction() {
        $errorId = $this->_getParam('id', null);           
        // e.g. redner error/error404.phtml 
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer('error$errorId');
    }
}
```